# Convert a DBObject to JSON

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jersey

I'm wondering how to parse DBObject to JSON, I'm using Jersey framework to create a restful service with Java, i want to load data from my MongoDB and convert it to JSON format and finaly display it in my web page.
Here is what i tried to convert a DBObject that contains data to display, to a JSON object :

```
  DBCursor cursor = dbUser.find();
  JSON json = new JSON();
  String dataUser = json.serialize(cursor);
```

But what i get it's a MongoDB format not a JSON, Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: Have you tried to DBObject.toString method?

Comment: Yes, but it returns the same MongoDb format ...

Comment: What do you mean by MongoDb format. Isn't that JSON compliant?

Comment: This is a MongoDB format { "_id" : { "$oid" : "id"} , "number" : 1 , "name" : "mkyong-1"}

Comment: Actually, this is also a valid JSON string ! you can even validate it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Have you tried by using [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html)?
I personally use the method `writeValueAsString(obj)`.

Answer (score 1):

//assign the cursor  to the DbObject

DbObject result= cursor.next();

//this line will convert the DbObject to JSONObject

JSONObject output = new JSONObject(JSON.serialize(result));

Comment: Answering questions without an explanation for why it is the answer isn't very helpful to the original poster.

Comment: Exactly code is:
JSONObject output = new JSONObject(new JSON().serialize(result));

Comment: This won't working for me, filling with null values.

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with .toString()?

```
DBObject printerVersion = mainDao.getPrinterVersion();
printerVersion.removeField("_id");
printerVersion.removeField("isDeleted");
return printerVersion .toString();
```